# Create branch from current working tree and reset to HEAD

Tags: git, branch

I currently work on a feature that turns out to be bigger than expected, so it's probably the best to create a branch to work on it. So I need to create a new branch from my current working directory and reset the master branch to the current HEAD so that some fixes to the production environment can be done.

Somehow this sounds like an easy task, yet I can't quite figure it out. Possibly due to my lack of sleep.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So, create a working branch:

```
git checkout -b working_branch
```

either commit or stash your changes

```
git add <files>
git commit -m "message"
```

OR

```
git stash
```

Go back to master

```
git checkout master
git reset HEAD
```

Comment: There's no point in doing `git reset HEAD` immediately after a `checkout`. There won't be any changes in the index, checkout of a branch updates the index to the checked out branch.

Comment: That is a bit of an overkill, assuming you commit in the new branch, the working tree should be clean.

Answer (score 16):

If you haven't yet made a commit then you don't need to move master, it's already at the current `HEAD`. You can just checkout a new branch with `checkout -b`, it doesn't need your working tree to be clean.

E.g.

```
git checkout -b newtopic
```

You are now on `newtopic` and can commit your working tree changes here. `master` doesn't need to move.