# Putting recent committed work on a branch in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I've been doing some work on the `master` branch. I've made several commits, but my commits aren't pushed yet. I've decided that the work is extensive enough that I should put it on a branch. (This sounds like [Create branch from current working tree and reset to HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2089882/421049) but in that question no commits had been made, so the questions are not identical.)

I'm an experienced Git user and I'm reasonably confident in theory that I can simply do the following:

```
git branch new-branch
git reset commit-before-start-of-work --hard
```

So if I wanted to put all the work I did after my last `push` on a branch, I would do:

```
git branch new-branch
git reset origin/master --hard
```

This seems logical and easy, but since I haven't done this or even thought of it until today, I wanted to ask before trying it out. Since I didn't find an identical question, perhaps it will be helpful to someone as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  Before starting, make sure that `git status` shows everything committed, since `git reset --hard` will replace the current index and work-tree contents without questioning you, even if they have not been committed anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I removed the `-b` designation, which I had mistakenly included from the `git checkout -b new-branch` form, which creates and switches to a new branch. I just now tried everything, and it works like a charm.